# AWS: connecting to Aurora from Lambda Java Script using IAM as authentication method

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I've been following this tutorial [[1]](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/iam-role-based-authentication-to-amazon-aurora-from-serverless-applications/) to connect to an Aurora RDS cluster from a lambda JavaScript function using IAM authentication. I'm able to get an authentication token, but not able to use the token to get a connection to the data base. Also, I followed these instructions [[2]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide) to get an authentication token from CLI, and then use the token to connect 'mysql' command tool. All good from the command line, this kind of tells me that I have followed correctly all the steps from [[1]](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/iam-role-based-authentication-to-amazon-aurora-from-serverless-applications/).

I'm stuck though. Although I can get an authentication token from my lambda, I can't use it to connect to my data base. My lambda is written in Java Script, and the mysql driver I'm using is [[3]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql). This driver seem to not be compatible with IAM authentication. Here is why I think that:

- in [[1]](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/iam-role-based-authentication-to-amazon-aurora-from-serverless-applications/), there is an example for Python, where a mysql driver is being used. In the example, the instructions tell to use

  ```
      auth_plugin="mysql_clear_password"
  ```

  and the driver I'm using [[3]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql), from docs, I can't find an option that maps to "auth_plugin". The closer, is a flag called PLUGIN_AUTH, but docs for [[3]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) say:

  ```
      Uses the plugin authentication mechanism when connecting to the MySQL server. This feature is not currently
      supported by the Node.js implementation so cannot be turned on. (Default off)
  ```

Seems like Node doesn't support this.

This is a piece of my code:

```
       const mysql = require('mysql');
       var config = {
                  host       : theHost,
                  user       : theUser,
                  password   : token, --------> token previously generated
                  database   : theDataBase
                  auth_plugin: "mysql_clear_password",   --------> this option is not really part of driver [3], I was just trying
                                                                                                      something out
                  ssl: {
                        ca: '/var/task/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem'  ----------> cert downloaded from [4]
                   }
         };
        var connection = mysql.createConnection(config);
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
          ERROR error connecting: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I have checked that "/var/task/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem" exists. It is part of the zip package for my function.

If I remove the "ssl" key from the connection object, I get:

```
          error connecting: Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol
          requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
```

From AWS docs, I can't find a good example of using IAM authentication from a Lambda function implemented in JavaScript. So, my questions are:

- If any, can you provide an example of a Lambda function implemented in Java Script of how to connect to Aurora using IAM authentication?
- Are you aware if really [[3]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) doesn't support IAM authentication?
- Is there any other mysql driver that is really compatible with IAM authentication?

Thanks!

References:

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/iam-role-based-authentication-to-amazon-aurora-from-serverless-applications/

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.AWSCLI.html

[3] https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

[4] https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem

Comment: Check out this example, I think it should work w/ the `mysql2` driver.  https://cloudonaut.io/passwordless-database-authentication-for-aws-lambda/

Answer (score 3):

a bit late but mysql library has rds certs inside it as standard

so luckily to solve this issue add 'ssl: "Amazon RDS",' which will use the inbuilt certs

so something like this

```js
const signer = new AWS.RDS.Signer({
        'region': region,
        'username': username,
        'hostname':host,
        'port': port
});
let token = await signer.getAuthToken({})
var config = {
                  host       : host,
                  user       : username,
                  password   : token, --------> token previously generated
                  database   : database
                  ssl: "Amazon RDS"
         };
```

see mysql docs for more

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#ssl-options

```
SSL options
The ssl option in the connection options takes a string or an object. When given a string, it uses one of the predefined SSL profiles included. The following profiles are included:

"Amazon RDS": this profile is for connecting to an Amazon RDS server and contains the certificates from https://rds.amazonaws.com/doc/rds-ssl-ca-cert.pem and https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
```

ps: word from the wise, aws rds to node is a bit tricky, there's lots of other tripropes like permissions, enabling iam, granting iam users to watch out for, create a question and ping me if you have other issues as well and i'll answer them there

Answer (score 0):

This is my working solution:

#### IAM

Make sure you have a policy like this attached to your function's execution role (snippet is ts CDK):

```js
lambda.addToRolePolicy(new PolicyStatement({
    effect: Effect.ALLOW,
    actions: [
        'rds-db:connect'
    ],
    resources: [
        'arn:aws:rds-db:us-east-1:{account id}:dbuser:{cluster resource id}/{db user name}'
    ]
))
```

#### In the Database

Make sure you have added the user, AND granted permission on the db you're trying to connect to:

```sql
CREATE USER {db user name} IDENTIFIED WITH AWSAuthenticationPlugin AS 'RDS';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON {db name}.* TO '{db user name}'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

#### In your Lambda function

I am using pools, you can do the same thing basically using a single connection. Also, I am using `mysql2` since it provides support for auth plugins which is required.

```js
const { Signer } = require('@aws-sdk/rds-signer')
const mysql = require('mysql2')

const { DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_USER, DB_NAME } = process.env

async function createPool() {
    const signer = new Signer({
        hostname: DB_HOST,
        port: DB_PORT,
        username: DB_USER
    })
    const token = await signer.getAuthToken()
    console.log('token: ', token)
    const dbConfig = {
        connectionLimit: 10,
        host: DB_HOST,
        user: DB_USER,
        database: DB_NAME,
        port: DB_PORT,
        password: token,
        ssl: 'Amazon RDS',
        authPlugins: {
            'mysql_clear_password': mysql.authPlugins.mysql_clear_password({
                password: token
            })
        }
    }
    return mysql.createPool(dbConfig)
}
```